# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer removing hash from url in angular 8

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

ngx-extended-pdf-viewer removing # from url angular
I am using "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^7.3.2", and  "zone.js": "~0.10.3"

I want to keep the # in my url:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true,})],
  exports: [RouterModule]`
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to version 10.0.0. It solves the bug.